# the EZ file explorer ftp on huawei pro 20 android 9

Tags: huawei, windows, file-transfer, ftp, emui

So i am trying to transfer some files from my pc to my android and both filezilla and the standrad windows explorer ftp wont connect i tried the 'wifi ftp' app on android store too but it wont connect to that either? using windows 10.

Comment: How your PC and Android are connected to each other? What address did you put in FileZilla?

Comment: its the standard ftp server that ez file explorer come with